# JSP - Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I’m preparing for OCEWCD. Below code is appearing in a jsp page

`<jsp:useBean id="acct1" class="aaa.bbb.Account"/>`

`<jsp:useBean id="acct2" class="aaa.bbb.Account " />`

And

`<jsp:setProperty name="acct2" property="address" value="${acct1.address}" />`

This code is trying to copy ”address” attribute of “acct1” object to “acct2” object’s  “address” attribute.

The explanation saying, the el expression (value="${acct1.address}") brings a reference to the address attribute of acct1 object.

But my understanding is, it will bring the string representation of the address attribute of acct1 object  ( like- acct1.getAddress().toString() ).

Because if the following code appearing in a jsp page,

```
<%
Request.setAttribute(“A”, new A());
%>
${A}
```

the output might be something like

> org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp$1A@1bcdccc3.

Explain me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion to String takes place only when the object is printed in the output:

```
<% Request.setAttribute(“A”, new A()); %>
${A} <%-- A.toString() is called here --%>
```

In `<jsp:setProperty name="acct2" property="address" value="${acct1.address}" />` nothing is printed to the output, so no string conversion takes places. In effect, this is the same as `acct2.setAddress(acct1.getAddress())`